# Pyinstaller executable appears as two processes

Tags: python, node.js, multithreading, pyinstaller, child-process

I have an executable (main.exe) that I've packaged with pyinstaller, appears to be functioning as expected. I execute main.exe from a nodejs server as a child_process and in task manager I can see 2 main.exe processes running.

It looks like this is a result of the bootloader: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced-topics.html#the-bootstrap-process-in-detail

" It begins the setup and then returns itself in another process. This approach of using two processes allows a lot of flexibility and is used in all bundles except one-folder mode in Windows. **So do not be surprised if you will see your bundled app as two processes** in your system task manager."

My issue is, how can I cleanly access and terminate this second process from within nodejs? Currently I terminate the original child process but am left with a single main.exe process running.

Comment: Same issue here, running via C# and need to terminate both/all processes. When running it in cmd, pressing ctrl C seems to terminate everything as expected. In C# unity, it worked as expected for one of my executables but for the other one only terminated 1 of them.